# Rails generator listed, but not found when running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I am in process of writing a Rails Engine, and as part of it I have a generator script that copies some migration files.

The generator is located here

```
lib/generators/install/install_generator.rb
```

The generator looks like this

```
module Calligraph
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
    ...
    ...
    end
end
```

In the host application, if I do a `rails g`, I see this along with other generators.

```
Calligraph:
  calligraph:install
```

If I hit

```
rails g calligraph:install
```

it comes back with

```
Could not find generator calligraph:install.
```

Any idea on what's missing/wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your generator to
`lib/generators/calligraph/install/install_generator.rb`.

Because your generator is defined within a module, Rails expects it to be contained within a subdirectory with the same name, just like namespaced controllers or other Rails extensions that live within modules.

Alternatively, you sometimes get a "could not find generator" error if you have a syntax problem in your generator, but the console would also spit out a trace and details on what that error would be if that were the case.

For your generator to work correctly, you also need to require `rails/generators` somewhere in your engine. I usually do it at the top of the generator file, but since `rails g` is picking up your generator it seems like you have taken care of it somewhere.

Comment: It was the folder convention, I did a `rails g generator install`, and missed the namespace.

Comment: Thanks zeiv. You saved my day! I have been struggling for hours with "could not find generator" without reading the complete stack trace. The problem was simply due to a stupid syntax error in my generator file.